# call to async Controller method from Web ApiController async controller method

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, asp.net-web-api, controller

I have following controller method

```
public class EmailController : Controller
{
    public async Task<ActionResult> SendEmail(UserData user)
    { 
        ...

        return View(user);
    }
}
```

I'm trying to call above`SendEmail` method and send `sampleData` object in below webapi controller method

```
[Authorize]
[RoutePrefix("api/Account")]
public class AccountController : ApiController
{

    // POST api/Account/Register
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [Route("Register")]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Register(RegisterBindingModel model)
    {

        // Email Sending
        UserData sampleData = new UserData();
        sampleData.Id = user.Id;
        sampleData.UserName = user.UserName;
        sampleData.UserEmail = user.Email;
        sampleData.FirstName = user.FirstName;
        sampleData.Password = model.Password;

        //Call to Async Controller method
        var emailSend = await EmailController.Sendemail(sampleData);
    }
}
```

How can I do this properly

Comment: Please, show us your project structure!

Comment: Are you asking how to send an email? If so, check out the SmtpClient class. It takes about 3 lines of code

Answer (score 0):

The `SendEmail` method on the `EmailController` is an `ActionResult`, therefore it should be concerned only with carrying out the necessary logic to update the view. Any business logic to send emails should be encapsulated in a separate layer, which can be called from both the view controller and the API controller.

Comment: Actually I'm not worrying about layered approach just want to send an email under action method, since its not worked under apicontroller method I moved it to a controller method